# SymmetricNAT error when using I2P on Windows 8

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, privacy

I'm trying to use [I2P](http://www.i2p2.de), an anonymizing network layer that's written in Java.
I've installed the service on Windows 8, but it reports a `SymmetricNAT` error. I have authorized the Java executables on my PC across locations (in `system32` as well as in `Program Files`) to accept incoming connections from outside in Windows Firewall. I've also opened one port on my router and set that as the port to use in the I2P console, to no avail.

This is a problem only since upgrading to Windows 8, it worked fine on 7 Ultimate that I had before.
Any solutions?